# How to integrate or connect the MetaMask wallet into the TokenLite ICO script?

Tags: metamask, ico

I have a TokenLite ICO script in which I need to integrate the MetaMask wallet, I can integrate CoinPayments but I don't want that.

Comment: Add more details to the question

Comment: I want to integrate MetaMask Wallet into my laravel token sale website, so whenever users clicks the buy button they are connected to their metamask wallet to pay for that